# How to implement a paginated list with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Without Compose we can handle with other Jetpack library, Paging Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) with compose.

For example

```
val customerList =dao.getAllCustomers().toLiveData(50)
```

where DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY name")
fun getAllCustomers():DataSource.Factory<Int, Customer>
```

But if your data source is coming from room database you should need to keep it in a separate module

And finally to display the LiveData list

```
@Composable
fun LiveDataCustomerListView(liveList:  LiveData<out List<Customer>>) {
    
    val list by liveList.observeAsState(initial =  emptyList<Customer>())
    AdapterList(data = list) { customer->

       Text("name:${customer.name}") 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is AdapterList able to refresh itself automatically by subscribing on the PagedList changes? Because PagedList is a special kind of list that is observable.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun LatestNewsFeed(viewModel: NewsViewModel) {
    val state = viewModel.newsState.collectAsState()
    val lastIndex = state.value.articles.lastIndex
    LazyColumnForIndexed(items = state.value.articles) { i, newsItem ->
        if (lastIndex == i) {
            onActive {
                viewModel.getMoreNews()
            }
        }
        NewsCard(newsItem) {
            viewModel.onSelectedNews(newsItem)
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example from my [post](https://medium.com/schibsted-tech-polska/list-pagination-with-jetpack-compose-6c25da053858) with working sample

The key elements here are:

1. Observe data from your model as `State`. Jetpack Compose supports converting `Flow`, RxJava, and `LiveData` into `State`. In my example, I was using `Flow`.
2. Use `onActive{}` as a trigger point. It is called only once on the first composition. In my case, I was checking if I have reached the last item but this logic could be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Let me update and complete @Damine answer. The point is you had to add e method inside view model that can get data with offset. Then you can pass your next offset to get data. You had to handle another state that says if this is in initial mode of network call or not? So first time you will get data from 0 then you will update ui with new data!

Lest see code. first you had to define state like this

```
enum class Status {
    INITIAL,
    LOADING,
    SUCCESS,
    FAILED
}

data class NetworkState private constructor(
    val status: Status,
    val msg: String? = null
) {
    companion object {
        val INITIAL = NetworkState(Status.INITIAL)
        val SUCCESS = NetworkState(Status.SUCCESS)
        val LOADING = NetworkState(Status.LOADING)
        fun error(msg: String?) = NetworkState(Status.FAILED, msg)
    }
}
```

And put network state in viewModel
Also you had to update state inside viewModel when get data change it to LOADING.

```
class ViewModel ... {
  private val _networkState = MutableStateFlow(NetworkState.INITIAL)
    val networkState: StateFlow<NetworkState> = _networkState

fun getDataWithoffset(offset : Int){

        _networkState.value = NetworkState.LOADING

//get data from server and update values

}
```

Then handle  it inside view like this:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun LatestNewsFeed(viewModel: NewsViewModel) {
    val state = viewModel.newsState.collectAsState()
    val netWorkstate = viewModel.networkState

if (netWorkstate.value == NetworkState.INITIAL) {
    viewModel.getDataWithoffset(0)
}
    val lastIndex = state.value.articles.lastIndex
    LazyColumnForIndexed(items = state.value.articles) { i, newsItem ->
        if (lastIndex == i) {
            onActive {
                viewModel.getDataWithoffset(lastIndex+1)
            }
        }
        NewsCard(newsItem) {
            viewModel.onSelectedNews(newsItem)
        }
    }
}
```